# Modify only one keyboard layer in .xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

My default keyboard layout looks like this

```
$ xmodkeymap -pke
```

```
...
keycode  38 = a A a A ae AE ae AE a A ae AE
...
```

I want to modify the part of the layout where `mode_switch` is pressed, that is, columns 3 and 4 should be changed, but all the other columns should stay the same.

Currently, I copied the old layout and replaced columns 3 and 4:

```
...
keycode  38 = a A Greek_alpha Greek_ALPHA ae AE ae AE a A ae AE 
...
```

However, it would be nicer if there was a way to write an `.xmodmap` file by *only* specifying the *differences* to the default keyboard layout.
Ideally, there would be some placeholder – let's call it `*` – that stands for the symbol used in the default layout. The same file could then be written as:

```
...
keycode  38 = * * Greek_alpha Greek_ALPHA * * * * * * * * 
...
```

I could write a script that generates an `.xmodmap` from a file like above, but I would prefer a built-in solution for `xmodmap`.